# Row animation not happening when inserting new row

Tags: ios, swift

I am following the "Start Developing iOS Apps [Swift]" tutorial and there seems to be a problem with animating a newly inserted row.  Here is the code that was provided in the tutorial.

[image]

For some reason no animation occurs

Answer (score 0):

Try to add before tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths
  tableView.beginUpdates()
And after insertRowsAtIndexPaths
  tableView.endUpdates()

Example:

```
tableView.beginUpdates()
tableView.insertRowsAtIndexPaths(indexPath, withRowAnimation: .Bottom)
tableView.endUpdates()
```

Comment: hmm no luck on the ".Bottom" animation but i changed the ".None" animation above it to give an animation and it works for that one.  I still have no idea why the other one doesnt work